# Stop Microsoft Security Essentials from continually asking to send a file

Tags: windows, ms-security-essentials

I use the cool Console Emulator project https://conemu.github.io/ to do console work on Windows when I'm developing. Over the past week, Security Essentials has asked several times a day if it can send in the exe or a related dll file. I've tried finding the appropriate setting to prevent this. Is there a way to stop this madness?

[image]

Comment: What's the setting for SpyNet?

Comment: Why not just send it in?  Have you tried creating an exclusion for that file yet?

Comment: Just add an exception for the file in question.

Comment: If I remember correctly, when installing the program, you can opt out of sending Microsoft analytical data. I don't ever recall seeing an option to disable/enable this once the program is installed, so perhaps try going through an uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have sent it in several times over the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem through these steps:

1. Open Microsoft Security Essentials window
2. Go to the "Settings" tab (the last one)
3. Select "**MAPS**" from the list on the left, and "I don't want to participate in MAPS" in the right part

No nasty questions from Microsoft from now on!